# Xcode 9.4.1: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7, arm64, x86_64

Tags: ios, cmake, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol, xcode9.4

I created a framework using CMake and added it to the test project. Then import the header file and everything works fine. I got this error when I call the method. I don't know why this error occurs. I tried almost all possible ways, but it didn't work. Any suggestions will be grateful.

**Issue**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "XmlInterface::XmlInterface()", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "XmlInterface::~XmlInterface()", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I have tried these methods**

1. `Other Linker Flags` add `$(inherited)`
2. delete `DerivedData`
3. set `NO` to `Active Architecture Only`

**lipo -info**

`Architectures in the fat file: xml are: x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64`

**Attached screenshot**

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbzSg.jpg)

Comment: Do not post images with text, add the text itself into the question post. This is about your first screenshot with the error message.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your suggestion, I will modify it right away.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiling with a binary that has been compile on simulator, but try to run the app on a real device.

The simplest way is to compile on device, then run on device. The hardest way is to check what can be done with "lipo" :)